# Remove group when the user is removed django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I've created a registration form where, when a user signs up, it automatically creates a group with the same name as the user's username and puts the new user in it. In this way, every user is inside a unique user group (that happen to have the same name as the user inside it).

Now, my problem is that, if I delete the user, the group clearly won't be deleted as well. Is there a way to automatize this process? So, delete user --> delete the group he/she/it was in there?

My code

### views.py

```
@unauthenticated_user
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration Succesfully")
            # every user is inside an unique group with its name
            Group.objects.get_or_create(name=username)
            group = Group.objects.get(name=username)
            group.user_set.add(user)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('register')
        else:
            pass
    else:
        form = RegisterUserForm()
    return render(request, 'authenticate/register_user.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use signals inside `models.py` such as

### models.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

@receiver(post_delete, sender=User)
def delete_user_group(sender, instance, *arg, **kwargs):
    group = Group.objects.get(name=instance.username)
    group.delete()
```